# modular inversion in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, modulo

I am reading Extended Euclid algorithm in Algorithms book by Sanjoy das gupta at followinglink page 33

http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL630/all.pdf

suppose we wish to compute `11^-1 mod 25`.
Using the extended Euclid algorithm, we find that `15 * 25 - 34 * 11 = 1`. Reducing both sides modulo 25, we have -34 * 11 congruent equal 1 mod 25. So -34 congruent equal 16 mod 25 is the inverse of 11 mod 25.

My question how author concluded that "-34 congruent equal 16 mod 25 is the inverse of 11 mod 25." from previous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `15 * 25 - 34 * 11 = 1` you have `15 * 25 - 34 * 11 = 1 mod 25` which leads to `-34 * 11 = 1 mod 25`.

If you have `a * b = 1`, than `a` is the multiplicative inverse of `b` regardeless if `a` and `b` are matrices, field elements or elements of a residual class ring.

You get the result 16 when you *normalize* -34 to the range between 0 and 24: `16 = 2 * 25 - 34`, and thus `16 * 11 = 1 mod 25`. Note: There is exactly one natural `k` with `k * 25 - 34` between 0 and 24, and this is 2 in this case.

Comment: @ Clemens thanks for answering. But my question is why 16 mod 25 is shown

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Comment: @ Clemens. Thanks for clarification. Now it make sense.